# React Datagrid with cards instead of columns?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

We love the [DataGrid](https://material-ui.com/components/data-grid/) for its build in [sorting](https://material-ui.com/components/data-grid/sorting/) and [filtering](https://material-ui.com/components/data-grid/filtering/) capabilities.

However grid based layouts are troublesome on small screen devices. So we started looking at [Card](https://material-ui.com/components/cards/) based layouts. There we miss the sorting and filtering we appreciate in the DataGrid.

Now we are wondering if there is an example to use cards as UI layer for the DataGrid, where a column in the grid would become a row in the card. Cards should flow to available columns.

How can we do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a partial answer, however, there is a `renderCell` prop in the column configuration that accepts a function that can include a component.

So, to replace a row with a card, I might include a column that renders your components with all of the values you would otherwise express one by one in a series of columns. For instance:

```
const columns = [
  { field: 'id', headerName: 'ID', hide: true }, // keep this
  { field: 'myCombinedView', hide: false, flex: 1, renderCell: (props) => <Component {...props} /> },
```

I can imagine including a single, hidden column that represents a concatenation of the values you want to sort on.  From here, specify the sort function for the `Component` column that uses the hidden value.

The following code sample is pulled from the `DataGrid` [storyboard](https://material-ui-x.netlify.app/storybook/?path=/story/x-grid-tests-sorting--custom-comparator):

```
() => {

  const columns = getColumns();

  // compute a new field for purposes of sorting
  columns[columns.length] = {
    field: 'username',
    valueGetter: (params) =>
      `${params.getValue('name') || 'unknown'}_${params.getValue('age') || 'x'}`,
    sortComparator: (v1, v2, cellParams1, cellParams2) => cellParams1.row.age - cellParams2.row.age,
    width: 150,
  };

  return (
    <div className="grid-container">
      <XGrid
        rows={getRows()}
        columns={columns}
        // use the field as the sort model
        sortModel={[{ field: columns[columns.length - 1].field, sort: 'asc' }]}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

How to dynamically select/change the sort criteria is not something I can see a clear path for.

Comment: How did this end up working out for you? Did you find a better solution?

Comment: I did not use this solution, but only because I did not have the issue.  I informed my answer from a "deep-dive" when I was learning about the v4 x-datagrid.  This included knowing about  storybook examples that might suggest a similar approach.  The v5 of mui may have updated the grid's api so maybe worth a review.

Comment: I got pretty far in using a card view, but it felt kind of hacky and future updates to mui could have broken the implementation. We decided against going this route.